# Calling sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following HTML structure:

I load a `Content` component on website load:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Content), document.getElementById('content'));
```

And inside this component I want to put another component into navigation div with some props, like:

```
var Content = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            isUserSignedIn: this.isUserSignedIn(),
            role: undefined
        };
    },

    isUserSignedIn: function () {
        return UserService.isSignedIn();
    },

    setIsUserSignedIn: function () {
        this.setState({
            isUserSignedIn: this.isUserSignedIn()
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        if (this.state.isUserSignedIn === false) {
            return React.createElement(UserSignIn, {setIsUserSignedIn: this.setIsUserSignedIn});
        } else {
            if (this.state.role !== undefined) {
                ReactDOM.render(
                    React.createElement(Navigation),
                    {role: this.state.role},
                    document.getElementById('navigation')
                );
            }
            return React.createElement('div', {}, '');
        }
    }

});
```

This however throws me an error that I can't use props inside the `ReactDOM.render` method (when the `role` is not undefined). How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your initial state, just set

```
isUserSignedIn: false
```

Your render() function should use JSX to create components (instead of React.createElement).  Those component will have to be included in your parent component with a reference to their js file, for example

```
 var Navigation = require('./Navigation');
```

You are passing the setIsUserSignedIn func from the parent to the child component.  It is not clear from your code where

```
UserService.isSignedIn()
```

is defined and called.

```
render: function () {
    if (this.state.isUserSignedIn === false) {
        return (<UserSignIn setIsUserSignedIn={this.setIsUserSignedIn} />);
    } else {
        if (this.state.role !== undefined) {
            return( <div id="navigation">
                       <Navigation role={this.state.role}/>
                     </div>
        }  else
           return (<div></div> )
        }
    }
}
```